# Ionic 5 Phonegap-NFC plugin not installed error when it's installed

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

When using the NFC library the Ionic docs recommend 
(https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc)
(https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc) I get a ''plugin not installed'' error when trying to reach the code in my component calling the ndef or nfc providers on my Android One Plus through the 'ionic serve --devapp' CLI command. It also says the devapp does not support this plugin, but I am unclear about how I am supposed to go about using this package testing wise in that case.

After specifying version 4 as per suggestion of this post for Ionic 3 I got a different error. This is with rxjs-compat installed and none of the nfc/ndef code actually used aside the imports in the module and component, and the injection into the constructor.

This is using  "import {Ndef, NFC} from '@ionic-native/nfc';" instead of /nfc/ngx like above.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at index.js:405
    at Module../node_modules/@ionic-native/nfc/index.js (index.js:599)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
```

When I try to build the app instead of serving it with the devapp I come across this (perhaps unrelated) error, even though I am running the app in Android Studio on Windows 10 and have both my Java, Android and Gradle paths defined in my environment variables.

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

I have added the imports and the provider in the app module.

```
import {Ndef, NFC} from '@ionic-native/nfc';

@NgModule({
...

  providers: [
    NFC,
    Ndef,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
```

This is how I inject the providers into my class.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {ToastController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {Ndef, NFC} from '@ionic-native/nfc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private nfc: NFC, private ndef: Ndef, private toast: ToastController) {

  }
```

Maybe I am completely on the wrong path about this, but following the documentation or any of the suggestion threads available on similar topics have not lead anywhere. Am I approaching this wrong?

EDIT: After running everything in a new project and making sure I go through each and every step without making any errors, I again end up with the INSTALL PLUGIN ERROR, like such.

```
[ng] [console.warn]: "Install the NFC plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc'"
[ng] [console.warn]: "Native: tried calling NFC.removeNdefListener, but the NFC plugin is not installed."
[ng] [console.warn]: "Install the NFC plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc'"
[ng] [console.log]: "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode."
[ng] [console.log]: "calling _sync"
[ng] [console.error]: "ERROR" "plugin_not_installed"
[ng] [console.info]: "[WDS] Live Reloading enabled."
[ng] [console.log]: "calling _reload"
[ng] [console.log]: "done _reloading"
[ng] [console.log]: "Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 836 ms"
```

This error appears in my console only when I open up the Android version of the app in DevApp after serving it with serve --devapp. It does not appear when I run it in the browser, it then just gives me the ''Cordova'' not available error, which I imagine is standard for plugins that don't work on certain devices. This is done following the exact step by step process, including the code in the ionic docs.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc

EDIT2: It might have to do with an XML processing error. When running through the same steps as before I came across an error I dismissed earlier when installing the plugin due to it resolving itself after installing both the iOS and Android platforms on Cordova. The error below happens after running the 'ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc' command. The plugin however DOES install, and is listed under 'cordova plugin list' afterwards, but the installation might not be done completely correctly. The plug-in is not listed under the plugins in config.xml for example.

```
Failed to install 'phonegap-nfc': Error: Unable to graft xml at selector "/manifest/uses-sdk" from "C:\Users\cliem\Desktop\dev\nfctest\nfctest2\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml" during config install
    at ConfigFile_graft_child [as graft_child] (C:\Users\cliem\Desktop\dev\nfctest\nfctest2\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigChanges\ConfigFile.js:122:19)
```

Comment: Can you put up steps you took to install the plugin? which rxjs version you are using?

Comment: Through the CLI, in my project I did 
```ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc
npm install @ionic-native/nfc```
I didn't initially specify any of the versions I worked with, so I assume I am running with the latest version/combination of Ionic4 and Angular.

Comment: I am asking about rxjs version.

Comment: I am using rxjs 6.5.3.

Comment: try this and check npm i rxjs@^6.0 rxjs-compat

Comment: After downgrading like this:
```
+ rxjs@6.0.0
+ rxjs-compat@6.5.3
added 2 packages from 6 contributors and audited 17567 packages in 18.738s
found 0 vulnerabilities

C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\TimeMaster\TimeTest>version-check rxjs
rxjs 6.5.3
```

I still get 

```
[ng] [console.warn]: "Install the NFC plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc'"
[ng] [console.error]: "ERROR" "plugin_not_installed"
```

Error even though Cordova plugin list says I have the plugin installed.

Comment: Apologies for the mark-up but it doesn't seem to want to work anymore in the comments with neither the single or triple backtick.

Comment: remove the nfc native plugin and try to access the methods like NFC.methodName()

Comment: ```    NFC.addTagDiscoveredListener(() => {
      console.log('ADDED TAGDISCOVERED LISTENER');
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('ERROR ADDING TAGDISCOVERED LISTENER');
    }).subscribe((event) => {
      console.log('RECEIVED TAGDISCOVERED MESSAGE: ', event.tag);
      console.log('TAGDISCOVERED:', NFC.bytesToHexString(event.tag.id));
    });```

I get the same exact error. It does now correctly recognize the plugin initially. It also tells me that the devapp might not be compatible with the NFC scanner.

Comment: Though building the app also does not work, be it that I'm not tracking any of the error logs then. It simply opens up the standard nfc screen when I scan my tag.

Comment: Now if you can consume the plugin this might be some other issues regarding the plugin.

Comment: What do you mean with ''consume''? 

On a different note, a coworker of mine just tried the same plugin on phonegap rather than ionic and it worked without any problem :s

Comment: Let me know if you can build the app and successfully consume the plugin ?

Comment: consume means if you are able to invoke a method from plugin and getting a response(success/failure).

Comment: Unfortunately no matter what method of approaching the plugin I try I just get a plugin not installed error or a Object is not a function error. I suppose the closest I got was not using the angular version of the native NFC library.

Comment: Try this repo and let me know if you can successfully  run the app or not https://github.com/ahmedelgohary/social-swap

Comment: For some reason I am unable to serve/build the app you have provided, even after reinstalling npm etc. It's giving me strange errors. I am going to try this on a different machine.

Comment: @Swayangjit I think you misunderstood maybe, the app still doesn't work and I cannot consume the plugin functions. It just starts the normal android nfc screen, and closes the app I actually want to scan it on as it always does when the plugin doesn't load correctly.

Comment: I got the project running now but it just pops up with ''try again later''. Scanning an NFC chip does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, don't use a Java version over 8. Nfc plugin does not work with ionic serve --devapp and needs to be tested with ionic cordova run android instead. Console needs to be read out from chrome://inspect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of cordova which is 9.0.0, try 
$ sudo npm uninstall -g cordova to uninstall it and install in back again with a previous version 
$ sudo npm uninstall -g cordova@8.x

This worked for me